# Rundeck ACL based on AD groups

Tags: active-directory, remote-access, rundeck

I am going to use Rundeck in production.

While reading docs, I found that users management is based on local ACL files.
And AD authentication is available.

My question is: Is it possible to manage users access to Jobs and Nodes by AD groups?

Fox example:
AD groups: rundeck_restrat_svcName1, rundeck_restrat_svcName2, ect..

Thanks for any information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. You can do that.

1, Create a jaas configuration file for AD, say jaas-AD.conf at /etc/rundeck folder like [this](http://rundeck.org/docs/administration/authenticating-users.html#active-directory)

2, Modify the *profile* file's two lines.

```
export RDECK_JVM="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/rundeck/jaas-AD.conf
-Dloginmodule.name=activedirectory
```

3,In AD create a new group, say *rundeck_users* and create an .aclpolicy file to set the ACL. There you have to use group as rundeck_users. You can create .aclpolicy file yml frame by [rd-acl](http://rundeck.org/2.5.0/man1/rd-acl.html) binary

Comment: The hyperlink of jaas-AD.conf returns 404, Is there another?